# Spring.NET: Enum to object mapping

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, spring.net

I have an enum `CommandType` with all possible commands. And I have a lot of classes having the same base class `Command`.

Then I can configure specific objects using the code like this:

```xml
<object type="Example.Command.MoveCommand">
    <property name="StepSize" value="10" />
</object>
```

Now I would like to create `Command` instances (each time a new one; not singleton) by `CommandType` value. How to configure such a mapping using Spring.NET?

Comment: What do you mean with "create instances by commandtype value"? Do you mean in your code?

Comment: Right now I create this mapping in Spring initilizing a Dictionary<CommandType,Command>. Of course, in this case I've got singleton Command object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [ServiceLocator](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#UsingAServiceLocator) functionality, which I don't think you can achieve with spring.net by only changing the configuration. Note that the `ServiceLocator` pattern is generally discouraged from a dependency-injection point of view, because it makes your object aware of its di container.

If you do need a `ServiceLocator` and don't mind tying your object to the Spring DI container, following *could be* a solution.

I assume your current code is something like this:

```
public class CommandManager
{
  Dictionary<CommandType, Command> { get; set; } // set using DI

  public Command GetBy(CommandType cmdKey)
  {
    return Dictionary[cmdKey];
  } 
}
```

Map the enum values to names of objects in you spring config by replacing your current `Dictionary<CommandType, Command>` with a `Dictionary<CommandType, string>`. Then use the current spring context to get the desired object:

```
using Spring.Context;
using Spring.Context.Support;

public class CommandManager
{
  Dictionary<CommandType, string> { get; set; } // set using DI; values are object names

  public Command GetBy(CommandType cmdKey)
  {
    string objName = Dictionary[cmdKey];
    IApplicationContext ctx = ContextRegistry.GetContext();

    return (Command)ctx.GetObject(objName);
  } 
}
```

Don't forget to set the scope of your command objects to `prototype`:

```xml
<object name="moveCommand" 
        type="Example.Command.MoveCommand, CommandLib"
        scope="prototype">
    <property name="StepSize" value="10" />
</object>
```

Now every time `CommandManager.GetBy(myKey)` is called, a new instance is created.